# Screenlet behaves like it has no underlying window

Tags: application-development, python, screenlets

I'm trying to write a screenlet from scratch following this guide http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-script-linux-desktop-1/index.html.
I have created the Hello World! example but when testing it I can't click on it, like the screenlet is being drawn directly on the desktop and it has no underlying window. When right-clicking on it the Desktop context menu appears. I tried printing **self.window** and this seems to be a regular **Gtk.Window** object.

Comment: What are you asking here?.

Comment: A reason for this behaviour and a minimal solution possibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that overriding on_draw_shape solves the problem, viz.

```
def on_draw_shape(self, ctx):
    ctx.paint()
```

I'm not sure this is the right solution though, nor I'm sure what the on_draw_shape event is for and how it differs from the on_draw event.